# Github pushing Netbeans 8

Tags: netbeans, github, push

I was hoping to do this without using command prompt, yet the Team menu doesn't have the Push option in Netbeans 8.0.  I already initialized the git.  Any suggestions?

[image: GithubPush]

Comment: If you initialized the repository then the "Team" menu should show different options. How did you do it?

Comment: right in that menu shown in the image file is how I initialized the repository.  yet the team menu remains unmodified.  im learning the command prompt way of doing it in the meanwhile

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure that the path is correct in the initialization step?

Comment: yeah.  I figured out the command prompt version, so I'm probably going to just let this topic go idle

Comment: ok, the problem was that my directory wasn't set to where the actual code was.  I set it to the github folder.  (I'm new to github, I thought the linking was done separately from that part).  Now I get the necessary Team options